# link not reading underscore and text after it

Tags: php

I have made one site which get the name from the database and display values from the data base.
Some of my database values having underscore (_) like abc_xyz.dll
But on get method it return only abc not the whole value abc_xyz.dll (skips the underscore and values after it)
Here is two links one having vales without underscore which works http://windllfiles.com/dlldata/SDACQ32MP.dll
Here is another link which have underscore which is not working
http://windllfiles.com/dlldata/ETA_USB.dll

Here is the code

> ('include/config.php');  $character = '';
> if(isset($_GET["character"]))    {
> $character = $_GET["character"];
> if($character=='09'){
>
> ```
>       $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_student WHERE student_name LIKE '0%'
>                                             or student_name LIKE '1%'
>                                             or student_name LIKE '2%'
>                                             or student_name LIKE '3%'
>                                             or student_name LIKE '4%'
>                                             or student_name LIKE '5%'
>                                             or student_name LIKE '6%'
>                                             or student_name LIKE '7%'
>                                             or student_name LIKE '8%'
>                                             or student_name LIKE '9%'
>         ";
>  }else{
>     $character = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#i', '', $character);
>     $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_student WHERE student_name LIKE '$character%'";  
> }
>       }    else    {  
>   $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_student ORDER BY RAND () LIMIT 30";    }    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);    ?>   <?php
> ```
>
> require 'include/header.php';
> ?>
>
> Get Your DLL
> file
>
> ```
>                  <?php  
>                       $character = range('A', 'Z');  
>                       echo ' <ul class="pagination alphabet_pagination">';  
>                       echo '<li><a href="/character/09/">0-9</a></li>';
>                       foreach($character as $alphabet)  
>                       {  
>                         echo '<li><a href="/character/'.$alphabet.'/">'.$alphabet.'</a></li>';   
>                       }  
>                       echo '</ul>';  
>                 
>                  ?>  
>                  
>                  </div>  
>                  <table class="table table-bordered">  
>                         <tr>   
>                            <th width="auto">All DLL Files</th>  
>                         </tr>  
>                       <?php  
>                       if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
>                       {  
>                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
>                            {  
>                       $name=$row["student_name"]
>
>                       ?>  
>                       <tr>  
>                              
>                           <td><?php echo '<a href="/dlldata/'.$name.'">'.$name.'</a>';?></td>  
>                            
>                       </tr>  
>                       <?php  
>                            }  
>                       }  
>                       else  
>                       {  
>                       ?>  
>                       <tr>  
>                            <td colspan="3" align="center">Data not Found</td>  
>                       </tr>  
>                       <?php  
>                       }  
>                       ?>  
>                  </table>  
>            
>        </div>       
>          </div>
>  <p> <?php include ('include/ads.php'); ?></p>   </div></div>
> <div class="col-sm-3">
>
> <?php include('include/right.php');?>
> ```

Here is the data file where I am using get method

> 'include/header.php';    $name = $_GET['name'];  ?>    
>   class="container-fluid">               Are you missing
>  File?   <div
> class="list-group-item list-group-item-action> 
>
>   Download  '.$name.'  
> File';?>
>
> <?php
>
> $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_student WHERE student_name='$name'";
> $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
>
> ```
>                      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
>                       {  
>                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
>                            {  
>           $id=$row["student_phone"]
>
>                       ?>  
>                       <li class='list-group-item'><p align="justify"><?php echo $id;?></p></li>  
>                            
>                        
>                       <?php  
>                            }  
>                       }  
>                       
>                       ?> 
>                       <br/> <?php $filename = "file/".$name; $filesize = filesize($filename); $filesize =round($filesize/1024, 2);
> ```
>
> echo "
>
> #### **File Information:**
>
> "; echo ""; echo "**File
> Size:**  ".$filesize.''; $md5file =
> md5_file($filename); echo "**MD5 file
> sum:**  ".strtoupper($md5file).''; $sha1file =
> sha1_file($filename); echo "**SHA1 file
> sum:**  ".strtoupper($sha1file).''; ?>    Download  '.$name.'  
> File';?>
>
> #### Dll Missing Error Message:

Comment: You have marked this as a php question, so presumably you have php code that handles the request. But you didn't show us the code, so there's really no way for anyone to help you.

Comment: It is not working only the database having underscore in text

Comment: Yes, I get that, but unless you show how you try to handle the request for the file, we won't be able to tell why it sometimes doesn't work. For instance, if those requests are for static files that exist in a `dlldata` directory, then you are not asking about php - it doesn't matter how the link was generated in your page. If that's the case you are asking about either apache or nginx configuration on a particular file system. But until you show us what you have set up to handle the GET request, php or server config or whatever, it's just not possible to tell what's wrong.

Comment: I have added code

Comment: so I gather from the code that php just creates the link but does not handle the GET request. The link you posted above should work if you simply type it into your browser. If it doesn't, then the problem is not php but server config, or the file is just misnamed or doesn't exist. For instance, if you're on Linux the file names will be case-sensitive.

Comment: I have added the codes

Comment: the code is not formatted properly and is kind of hard to read, but debugging would start with manually trying `SELECT * FROM tbl_student WHERE student_name='ETA_USB.dll'` - if that gives you the result you expect, then you should be able to use `ls` (on linux) to confirm that a file with that exact name is in the right place.

Comment: I have tried but link return as ETA not ETA_USB.dll

Comment: If the information in your database is incorrect, you need to look at how it was inserted.